# What is the return type of the STL algorithm "count", on a valarray

Tags: c++, iterator, valarray

I'm using `Visual Studio 2010 Pro` on a `Windows 7 64bit` machine and I want to use `count` (from the `<algorithm>` header) on a `valarray`:

```
int main()
{

  valarray<bool> v(false,10);
  for (int i(0);i<10;i+=3)
         v[i]=true;

  cout << count(&v[0],&v[10],true) << endl;

  // how to define the return type of count properly?
  // some_type Num=count(&v[0],&v[10],true); 
}
```

The output of the program above is correct:

```
4
```

However I want to assign the value to a variable and using `int` results in compiler warnings about loss of precision. Since `valarray` has no iterators, I can't figure out how to use the `iterartor::difference_type`.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Please clarify. You want to assign the output to same variable? Well, I guess `int x = count(&v[0],&v[10],true);` is not what you are looking for? If not, what else do you mean precisely?

Comment: Well, count()  returns a std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::difference_type. Is casting it to int is considered as defined behavior? for int c=count(&v[0],&v[10],true); I am getting compiler warning - possible loss of data.

Comment: Can you afford upgrading to a C++11 compiler? C++11 fixed a lot of things for `valarray`, among them supplying it with iterators.

Comment: In newer versions you could use `auto` but I don't think VS2010 supports that yet. Is upgrading an option (you can use the Community Edition freely).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct type for `Num` would be:

```
typename iterator_traits<bool*>::difference_type
    Num=count(&v[0],&v[10],true);
```

The reason for this is, that `count` always returns:

```
typename iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type
```

and your `InputIt` is a pointer to bool:

```
&v[0];   // is of type bool*
&v[10];  // is of type bool*
```

For me `iterator_traits<bool*>::difference_type` evaluates to `long` so you might also get away with simply using:

```
long Num=count(&v[0],&v[10],true);
```

However I have to admit I did not test it under `Visual Studio 2010 Pro` explicitly.